# How to pass a method as argument to a function in Scala using Py4J?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I'm using PySpark and want to pass a method of an object as argument to a function call in Py4J. I have a library in a `.jar` file, which has a method with this signature (abstracting away details of other parameters):

```scala
def apply(name: String, exp: Column => Column): SomeClass = { ... }
```

Suppose it belongs to `SomeClass` companion object, inside a package called `some.pkg`. After loading the jar into PySpark, I'm trying to call this method like this:

```py
>>> spark._jvm.some.pkg.SomeClass.apply("", spark._jvm.org.apache.sql.functions.hour)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1296, in __call__
    args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1266, in _build_args
    [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1266, in <listcomp>
    [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part
    command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
AttributeError: 'JavaMember' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Apparently, Py4J does not support passing methods as arguments to other functions, but I'm not sure. Is there some way to get around this?